# Android:Sqlite tables

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created tables in android sqlite using create statement and also inserted  values into it.
Now I need to see these tables to look at the table structure. I don't know how to see them?
Can anyone tell me where is the .db file located in the project.And how to check these tables.

Following is my code for it:

```
    String ctable= "Create Table offers_all(record_id TEXT,display_name TEXT,sorting_name TEXT,latitude NUMERIC,longitude NUMERIC,custom_ad_banner_resource_id TEXT,description TEXT,website_url TEXT,phone_number TEXT,hours TEXT,tasting_room TEXT,advertiser TEXT,street_address TEXT,offer_id TEXT,offer_section TEXT,start_date TIMESTAMP,end_date TIMESTAMP,custom_leaf_template TEXT,location_area TEXT)"


   database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ offers_all);
   database.execSQL(offers_all);


   Insert into offers_all(record_id,display_name,sorting_name,latitude,longitude,custom_ad_banner_resource_id,description,website_url,phone_number,hours,advertiser,street_address,offer_id,offer_section,start_date,end_date,custom_leaf_template,location_area)  values (  '23423-2134','Second Offer','second offer','-123.234234','32.42343','','Another Example of a Winery.','http=>//somewinery.com/','1.510.555.1212','10:45 am - 2:30pm','Yes','500 Yajome Street,11-10 10:44:10.599: Calistoga, CA, 94333','','','2011-08-24','9999-12-31','','Sonoma Valley')
```

Comment: Well, for one the table structure is defined in the SQL statement you executed

Comment: i need to see whether the structure has been made acc to my requirement and are the values being inserte to it or not?

Comment: The info below in the answer is on page one of Data Storage topics in the Dev Guide. You gotta at least read the guide and try. That's why I commented and not answered..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your android application's database file is stored in `/data/data/<package_name>/database` directory.

You can access it by `ddms file explorer` or via `adb shell`, `pull from device` then you can see it in **SQLite Manager** or **Eclipse SQlite plugins**.

**Also you can write query in adb shell for check existing data in your database.**

Comment: there is not any folder inside data folder in ddms

Comment: FYI, If you are testing the app on emulator then and then you can have /data/data/package/database directory otherwise you can't see database while testing on real device.

Comment: @ekjyot - If you are testing it with device the you can't see it, with ddms because your device is not rooted. Emulator will allowed you that,

Comment: K fine I got the folder but it is not getting opened